# Replicating "Timespan" of sim's backwards compatible syntax

Tags: matlab, simulink

TLDR:

In short, what's the best way to rewrite

```
time = 0:0.1:10;
[T,X,Y] = sim('model',time)
```

in the "modern" Simulink syntax that doesn't take an explicit time input?

---

It appears I'm rather out of date w.r.t. my Simulink usage.
The "current" syntax for running Simulink models programmatically is:

```
simOut = sim(model,'Name','Value',…)
simOut = sim(model,ParameterStruct) 
simOut = sim(model,ConfigSet)
```

Where the documentation gives all sort of complex ways to set up the arguments to use here.

The "old" (pre-2009b) syntax for Simulink is slightly different:

```
time = 0:0.1:10;
[T,X,Y] = sim('model',time)
```

Here, `time` is like the argument to the function `ode45`; it can specify a vector of times at which to return values, even when a variable-step size solver is being used.

How can this behaviour be replicated in `sim`'s "modern syntax"? I've tried the following approach:

```
simOut = sim(mdl,'OutputOption','SpecifiedOutputTimes','OutputTimes','time');
```

But this gives me the following error:

> Invalid OutputTimes specified in the Configuration Parameters dialog for block diagram '…'

And using the simpler

```
simOut = sim(mdl,'OutputTimes','time');
```

runs "correctly" with `tout` as specified, but none of the saved signals have a matching length. I feel like I've missed something obvious, and I've certainly killed too much time on this already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [name/value pairs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html#namevaluepairarguments) that are accepted by the [`sim`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html) function can be any of the [model parameters](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/model-parameters.html) that you can also specify via the [Configuration Parameters Dialog Box](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/configuration-parameters-dialog-box-overview.html). It also appears that the values have to be in the same format as they are normally entered into the configuration GUI. The [`OutputTimes`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/output-times.html) parameter is entered into an editable text box, meaning that it must be a character array defining a matrix of times at which Simulink should generate output. I would expect the following to work, and be equivalent to the old syntax:

```
simOut = sim(mdl, 'OutputOption', 'SpecifiedOutputTimes', 'OutputTimes', '0:0.1:10');
```

It *should* also work if you replace the `OutputTimes` parameter with the name of a variable in the workspace storing the times:

```
times = 0:0.1:10;
simOut = sim(mdl, 'OutputOption', 'SpecifiedOutputTimes', 'OutputTimes', 'times');
```

**EDIT:** One additional issue is to make sure that the maximum time in `OutputTimes` does not exceed the simulation [`StopTime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/gui/stop-time.html). Here's an example using a [built-in bouncing ball model](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/examples/simulation-of-a-bouncing-ball.html) with a default `StopTime` of 25 seconds:

```
>> simOut = sim('sldemo_bounce', 'OutputOption', 'SpecifiedOutputTimes', ...
                                 'OutputTimes', '0:0.1:25');  % No error
>> simOut = sim('sldemo_bounce', 'OutputOption', 'SpecifiedOutputTimes', ...
                                 'OutputTimes', '0:0.1:30');  % OutputTimes too long
Invalid OutputTimes specified in the Configuration Parameters dialog for
block diagram 'sldemo_bounce'

>> simOut = sim('sldemo_bounce', 'OutputOption', 'SpecifiedOutputTimes', ...
                                 'OutputTimes', '0:0.1:30', ...
                                 'StopTime', '30');  % Extend StopTime, no error
```

Comment: Thanks for the response — indeed, the distinction between needing arguments as character arrays did trip me up at some point. But I'm afraid your suggestion gives the same error ("Invalid OutputTimes specified…").

Comment: @WillRobertson: Could the problem be what I mentioned in my edit, a mismatch between `StartTime`/`StopTime` and `OutputTimes`?

Comment: You have got to be kidding me. Yes, that's the problem! Thanks so much. FWIW, it also seems to work for me with something like `'StopTime','Tmax'` — i.e., variable names passed as strings are evaluated in the current workspace. Not sure if there's any further limitations on that.